# Join data from few tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to joins a column from few tables.

I have:

```
- a table (TableALL) with all names
- 5 tables (table1,..,table5) that have the same structure (columns)
- one table (Description).
```

I am looking for something like:

```
For each name_id from TableALL {
If name_id in Table1 GET desc FROM DEScriptions where descriptions.desc_id=table1.desc_id ELSE write 'x'
If name_id in Table2 GET desc FROM DEScriptions where descriptions.desc_id=table2.desc_id ELSE write 'x'
...
}
```

Results:

```
Name_id, Name, Table1, TAble2, ..., Table5
1, Aloha, basic, premium, basic, 'x', 'x' (exist in some tables)
...
33, Zonk, 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x' (not exist in any table)
```

More info:

```
TAble1,...,TAble5: id, name, name_id, desc_id
TAbleAll: name_id, name
TAbleDesc, desc_id, desc
```

Comment: You can do a UNION of the 5 tables and join allNames with the Union. If you need to know the name of the source table in the results you can include a column with the table's name in each table's SELECT. At this point you can process the data on the client side or pivot the rows which can be a bit of a mess

Comment: Could you show us the exact names of your 5 tables and columns ?

Comment: Where does the `DEScriptions` come from ?

Comment: I suggest: either don't make important changes in your question, or at least reward the answers for your original version as well... good bye.

Comment: @PeterHorvath: IMHO I did not make important changes, just clarified and fixed misspellings.

Comment: Which made my work pointless.

Comment: Could you provide us some sample data for each table?  We need to know how `Aloha`, `basic`, and `premiusm` are stored in your tables.

Answer (score 0):

At a basic level you need to use a JOIN like this :

```
SELECT * FROM allNames AS all 
LEFT JOIN DESCriptions AS desc 
ON all.name_id = desc.id
```

That will link both tables together where name_id in table 1 and id in the other table are the same. It will return all columns in both tables or you can replace * with the column names

Edit:
If I get you correctly the solution should be as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM allNames as a
LEFT JOIN TAble1 as T1 ON a.name_id = T1.name_id
LEFT JOIN TAble2 as T2 ON a.name_id = T2.name_id
LEFT JOIN TAble3 as T3 ON a.name_id = T3.name_id
LEFT JOIN TAble4 as T4 ON a.name_id = T4.name_id
LEFT JOIN TAble5 as T5 ON a.name_id = T5.name_id
LEFT JOIN TAbleDesc as desc ON (desc.desc_id = T1.desc_id OR desc.desc_id = T2.desc_id OR desc.desc_id = T2.desc_id OR desc.desc_id = T2.desc_id OR desc.desc_id = T2.desc_id)
```

That should work and will send you all columns from all tables - only thing I have left out is renaming blank fields with an 'x' - they will just return as blank or null depending on how you've formatted the columns in the table. If you must have the x - it can be done programatically, but it will be easier to set the columns to be NOT NULL DEFAULT 'x'.

Comment: Peter: and where are date from 5 tables[1-5]?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you wanted some like a "for-loop" in SQL, which doesn't exist. Some procedural solution worked, but MySQL doesn't have one. Thus the nearest solution for his problem is to create the query in the container language.

What you can do is that you construct the query from the outer language (maybe php? You didn't wrote anything about it), and let run that.

An example solution in perl:

```
my $query_sel="SELECT Table1.name";
my $query_from="FROM Table1";
foreach (@allNames) {
    $query_sel=$query_sel.", COALESCE('".$_.", 'x') AS ".$_;
    $query_from=$query_from." LEFT JOIN ".$_." ON Table1.id=".$_.".desc_id";
}

MYSQL->exec($query_sel." ".$query_from);
```

This JOIN-based solutions gave `NULL` -s and instead of your wished `'x'`-es. This can be handled by the `COALESCE` function in MySQL.

`COALESCE(tableName.columnName, 'x')` will give you exactly what you want: the value of the column if it exists, and an `'x'` if it doesn't.

Comment: Not only can you do something like this with relatively simple SQL, but constructing the SQL statement like this exposes you to SQL injection attacks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Not if the `@allNames` is hardcoded, which is very likely from the question.

Comment: In which case, why not write the statement directly?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Because exactly this is what the OP wants to avoid. He wants some like a "for-loop" in SQL, which doesn't exist. Some procedural solution worked, but MySQL doesn't have one, thus the nearest solution for his problem is to create the query in the container language.